# Detectar una letra repetida y contigua en un array con map y filter

Tags: javascript

Primero que todo, sé que es muy fácil pero por favor no sean tan duros conmigo, a penas estoy aprendiendo javascript.

Estoy tratando de hacer esto: detectar una letra repetida contigua en un array pero con map y filter para que devuelva el item que la contiene. Con un loop for me funcionó más o menos como el ejemplo de abajo pero lo necesito es hacerlo con map y filter.

```
for (let i = 0; i < inventors.length; i++) {
     const letters = inventors[i].last.split("");
     for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
         if (letters[i] === letters[i + 1]) {
         }
     }
}
```

Así que intenté hacerlo así pero no me funciona, me devuelve un array vacio:

```
const letters = inventors.map(item => item.last.split(""));
const repeatedLetters = letters.filter(letter => letter === letter +1);
```

Estos son los datos:

```
        const inventors = [
        { first: "Albert", last: "Einstein", year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
        { first: "Isaac", last: "Newton", year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
        { first: "Galileo", last: "Galilei", year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
        { first: "Marie", last: "Curie", year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
        { first: "Johannes", last: "Kepler", year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
        { first: "Nicolaus", last: "Copernicus", year: 1473, passed:1543},
        { first: "Max", last: "Planck", year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
        { first: "Katherine", last: "Blodgett", year: 1898, passed: 1979},
        { first: "Ada", last: "Lovelace", year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
        { first: "Sarah E.", last: "Goode", year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
        { first: "Lise", last: "Meitner", year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
        { first: "Hanna", last: "Hammarström", year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
        ];
```

Si me pueden decir que estoy haciendo mal lo agradecería.

Comment: Seria bueno poder mirar la estructura basica ejemplo de inventors, ya que segun veo es un arreglo de objetos??

Comment: ¿Es un *array* de *strings* y tratas de sacar el *string* que tenga una letra repetida o cómo? Como dice @Riven, podrías enseñarnos un ejemplo de ese *array* `inventors` y el resultado que esperas obtener para que podamos entenderlo mejor.

Comment: Claro, lo adjunto arriba. La idea es filtrar por los items que contengan una letra repetida en el apellido por ejemplo Goode. Gracias.

Comment: @MacoAcero, ¿la repetición tiene que ser consecutiva o puede darse en cualquier parte del *string*?

Comment: Tiene que ser consecutiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas filtrar cuales objetos contienen por lo menos una letra contigua, entonces puedes usar solo `filter` no requieres y **no deberías usar map**, puesto que map **siempre te va a devolver un array del mismo tamaño que tenias en un principio**, la diferencia entre `map` y `filter` es que map puede transformar cada valor de un array en otro dependiendo de condiciones, mientras que filter no puede hacer esto, simplemente añade o no a un array el objeto en cuestión dependiendo de si se cumple o no una condición.

Para lograr lo que deseas deberas obligatoriamente usar un `filter` dentro de un `filter` (si no deseas hacerlo con un ciclo for):

```js
const inventors = [
   { first: "Albert", last: "Einstein", year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
   { first: "Isaac", last: "Newton", year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
   { first: "Galileo", last: "Galilei", year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
   { first: "Marie", last: "Curie", year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
   { first: "Johannes", last: "Kepler", year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
   { first: "Nicolaus", last: "Copernicus", year: 1473, passed:1543},
   { first: "Max", last: "Planck", year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
   { first: "Katherine", last: "Blodgett", year: 1898, passed: 1979},
   { first: "Ada", last: "Lovelace", year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
   { first: "Sarah E.", last: "Goode", year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
   { first: "Lise", last: "Meitner", year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
   { first: "Hanna", last: "Hammarström", year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const contiguousInventors = inventors.filter(el => {
  return el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
});

console.log(contiguousInventors);
```

Expliquemos un poco el codigo, veamos esta parte de aqui:

```
const contiguousInventors = inventors.filter(el => {
  return el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
});
```

primero hacemos el primer filter, el cual va iterar atravez de cada pocision de tu array `inventors`, dentro de `inventors` segun tengo entendido la propiedad que deseas que sea filtrada es la propiedad `last`, entonces dentro del filter usamos la propiedad last de cada uno de tus objetos para poder realizar el filtro:

```
el.last
```

Si bien estos dos procesos pueden ser escritos en una sola linea:

```
const contiguousInventors = inventors.filter(el => el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0);
```

Decidi mas que todo por legibilidad hacerlo en 3 lineas:

```
const contiguousInventors = inventors.filter(el => {
  return el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
});
```

La siguiente linea a analizar es esta:

```
return el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
```

Ponemos `return` puesto que el resultado al no estar en una sola linea y teniendo `{}` (llaves) dentro de nuestro primer `filter` deberemos indicarle explicitamente a nuestro primer `filter` nuestro valor de retorno, que sera el resultado de la condicion:

```
el.last.split("").filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
```

**La cual siempre retorna un booleano**.

Entonces dividimos la cadena de texto last por cada caracter:

```
el.last.split("")
```

Luego al tener un array de caracteres de la palabra, hacemos un `filter` de este array, para poder darnos cuenta de si en algun momento la condición se nos cumple y por lo tanto obtenemos aunque sea una coincidencia (un valor consecutivo).

```
filter((letter, j, r) => j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false).length > 0;
```

Cuando tenemos el 3er parametro en un map o filter, estamos haciendo referencia al arreglo original del cual deriva nuestro filter.

Dentro de la condicion del filter tenemos:

```
j > 0 ? r[j] === r[j - 1] : false
```

Lo cual es lo mismo que decir que si nos encontramos en el segundo elemento o superior, comparemos el actual con el anterior para ver si son iguales, y en caso de serlo retornamos `true`, de lo contrario retornamos `false`.

Por ultimo, al resultado de este `filter`, que debe ser un `array`, le miramos su longitud, esta sera la condicion de retorno booleana de nuestro segundo `filter` la cual afectara directamente el filtro que hará o no nuestro primer `filter`:

```
.length > 0
```

Lo cual significa en pocas palabras que si hay coincidencias de letras contiguas entonces que añada ese objeto al array (`true`) de lo contrario no (`false`).

Comment: Una cosa mas... se me ha olvidado que no sabia si querias distinguir entre mayusculas y minusculas, por defecto mi codigo distingue entre mayusculas y minusculas, por lo cual es importante que si no deseas distinguir entre mayusculas y minusculas hagas una pequeña modificacion a mi codigo, donde transformes ambos valores (r[j] y r[j - 1]) ya sea a mayusculas o a minusculas ambos, (solo si no deseas hacer distincion entre mayusculas y minusculas).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Y sobre todo por la explicación, genial que te hayas tomado la molestia. A penas estoy aprendiendo y me es de mucha utilidad: ya te di un punto pero no me aperece por no tener reputación aún. Gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, recuerda que si te ha sido de ayuda mi respuesta puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo ;3

Answer (score 0):

He tomado tu ejemplo y lo he adaptado según tus necesidades

```
inventors.map((person) => {
        first_name = person.first
        separated_name = Array.from(first_name)
        separated_name.filter((letterName, index) => {
            if(typeof(separated_name[index + 1]) != "undefined" && letterName == separated_name[index + 1]){
                console.log("El nombre (" + first_name + ") repite la letra (" + letterName + ")")
            }
        })
    })
```

En realidad este ejemplo no es el mejor, ya que `filter()` lo uso como iterador y no como lo que realmente es, una función de filtrado que debería comprobar algo.

```
inventors.map((person) => {
        first_name = person.first
        separated_name = Array.from(first_name)
        repeated = separated_name.filter((letterName, index) => {
            return typeof(separated_name[index + 1]) != "undefined" && letterName == separated_name[index + 1]
        })
        if(repeated.length > 0){
            console.log("El nombre (" + first_name + ") repite las letras (" + repeated.join(",") + ")")
        }
    })
```

Este seria un ejemplo más adecuado a un "uso correcto", a lo que quiero llegar con esto es que muchas de estas funciones tienen un cometido, si bien todas iterarán debes usarlas con el fin que fueron creadas.

Puedes leer más sobre estas y otras funciones en:
[Funciones de Array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ya te di un punto pero no me aperece por no tener reputación aún. Gracias

Comment: @MacoAcero Los puntos son lo de menos, lo importante de la respuesta es el enlace, ahí podrás encontrar todas las funciones disponibles para los `array` junto a su explicación, uso correcto y ejemplos en código.